# Where to find this green transparent brick?

Tags: piece-information, shopping, lego-store

Where can I find this lego brick?

[image]

I have one but I want some more of them for a project.

Answer (score 8):

Your brick appears to be trans-neon-green, an extremely rare color for 2x4 bricks. It never appeared in any set and it is only traded between collectors. You would be paying over $50 for a brick like that if you are lucky enough to find it. It would probably be best to pick another color, or another brick-size for your project. Trans-neon-green also comes in 1x2 size, which is more readily available.

Comment: So basically, the better path is to sell this one brick for $50 on bricklink.com, and then use the money to buy a larger quantity of the same brick in trans-yellow for ~$2 each :)

Comment: I guess that could work, although as a collector myself, I would never part from a brick like that. It is ultra-rare! :)

Comment: If it never appeared in any set, is an official brick and (I presume) was not available in pick-a-brick... What's their story? How did the collectors get their hands on them?

Comment: @Maurycy  LEGO does make uniquely colored pieces for LEGOLAND Parks and other special LEGO projects like large sculptures, etc. And they also make pieces in test colors (2x4 bricks are one of the most common for testing colors). Sometimes these escape the factories and design studios, make it to the secondary market, and end up in the hands of LEGO fans. They are highly valued by collectors.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be this one: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3001f1 ? In translucent yellow it sells for about $2 a piece and is also quite rare.

Comment: I have thought of that, but the OP's photo definitely looks more neon color than yellow. Especially at the edges. It could be just picture quality though. Trans-yellow is definitely easier to find. You linked to the one with frosted interior, and there is also the regular one listed here: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?P=3001&colorID=19

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this answer, 8 are listed in Bricklink:

[image]

They appear slightly different than the one in the photo though:

[image]

You get a discount if you buy more than one.  For only $275.00-ish USD they can be yours!  That is going to be one very expensive MOC :D

Answer (score -2):

**Could [this](http://www.bricklink.com/store.asp?p=gizmocom&itemID=23586764) be what you're looking for?**

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Ouch, that hurts.